# Vertical Histogram in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is a simple coding exercise. Given a list of integers output a vertical histogram showing how many of each number are in the input list. If the lis is empty output an empty string.

```
List(5, 2, 3)

*  
*  
* *
***
***
```

I wrote a function as follows:

```
def hist(l: List[Int]) = if(l.isEmpty) "" 
  else Range(l.max, 0, -1).map(i => l.map(x => if(i <= x) "*" else " ").mkString)
```

How would you solve this problem ?

P.S. Forgot to say you need to output the resulting strings

```
val r = hist(List(5, 2, 3))
r.foreach(s => println(s))
```

Comment: Consider also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24536215/3189923 on Scala histogram calculation.

Comment: Note answer update...

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think this is probably the right way to solve it. Let's wait for votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type from empty list check differs from the general case; consider this update,

```
def hist(l: List[Int]): IndexedSeq[List[String]] = 
  if(l.isEmpty) 
    Vector(List("")) 
  else 
    Range(l.max, 0, -1).map(i => l.map(x => if (i <= x) "*" else " "))
```

Then for `List(5, 2, 3)`,

```
hist(List(5, 2, 3))
res: Vector(List(*, " ", " "), List(*, " ", " "), List(*, " ", *), List(*, *, *), List(*, *, *))
```

and so for vertical printing,

```
hist(List(5, 2, 3)).foreach(v => println(v.mkString))

*  
*  
* *
***
***
```

**Update**

Let `val a = List(5, 2, 3)`, then a one-liner is like this,

```
a.map(v => " " * (a.max - v) + "*" * v).transpose.foreach(x => println(x.mkString))
```

Comment: Like the oneliner. Now I think it is really much better to build a _horisontal_ histogram first and then just transpose it.

Comment: noticed now @ChrisMartin had already provided a very similar idea to the update in this answer, thus to credit his approach. :)

Comment: Yes. Looks like @ChrisMartin's solution was the first. It is nice too but looks a little more verbose.

Comment: @Michael agree first, yet more verbose

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd write the function you implemented:

```
def hist(xs: Seq[Int]): String =
  xs.map(i => Seq.fill(i)('*').padTo(xs.max, ' '))
    .transpose.reverse.map(_.mkString).mkString("\n")
```

But wouldn't a histogram of `Seq(5,2,3)` look more like

```
 ** *
12345
```

?

Comment: Thanks. The transposition is probably the _right_ way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of readability I'd do this instead:

```
def hist: List[Int] => IndexedSeq[List[String]] = {
  case Nil => Vector(List("")) 
  case xs  => Range(xs.max, 0, -1).map(i => xs.map(x => if(i <= x) "*" else " "))
}
```

As I believe cases are easier to read and reason about than if statements

Running it looks like this:

```
scala> hlist(List(5, 2, 3)).foreach(x => println(x.mkString))
*
*
* *
***
***
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose but I believe more Scala-way:

```
object Histogram {
  def hist(list:List[Int]):List[String] ={
    val max = list.max
    val matrix = list match{
      case Nil => Nil
      case _ =>{
        list map (l => "*" * l)
      }.map{
        s => s + (" " * (max - s.length))
      }
    }

    (0 to max-1).reverse map (
      i => (for (s <- matrix) yield s(i).toString).mkString
    ) toList
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit ={
    hist(List(5,2,3,7,4)).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Few good points:
1) you don't need to use if `l.isEmpty` since Scala has `Nil` for that

2) pattern matching is always good for decomposition

3) you need to have simple `List[String]` as a result and not the `IndexedSeq[List[String]]`, so use `IndexedSeq.toString` method to convert